# Is there a way to compile Pascal program and put the generated files in a specific folder?

Tags: pascal, freepascal

So I am trying to compile Pascal programs and everything is fine; however, I would like to put the generated files after each compilation is a separated folder. I am looking of something like this: fpc "Destination Folder" "program.pas".

Thanks

Comment: Doesn't `fpc` have a `-o` option that enables you to set the output filename? Almost every compiler does.

Comment: Yea I am, and I am not trying to rename the output file(s) I am trying to make them generated in a specific folder.

Answer (score 2):

From [Alphabetical listing of command line options](http://www.freepascal.org/docs-html/user/userap1.html)

```
-FE<x>     Set exe/unit output path to <x>
-FU<x>     Set unit output path to <x>, overrides -FE
```

So something like fpc program.pas -FEc:\output should work. I don't have fpc installed so I cannot verify. If you try it and get errors that you can't work through post them.

Comment: Can you please provide an example? Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

This one works for me:

```
fpc hello.pas -o"Web/hello.cgi"
```

I was using ubuntu, notice there is no space between the argument -o and the beginning of the path "Web/..."